# Receive gcm message using jquery?

Tags: jquery, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing a rest service with node.js that send gcm notifications.
I am using:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

sender.send(message, {registrationTokens: regTokens}, function (err, response) {
    });
```

Is it possible to receive gcm message using jquery?

Comment: I solved my problem. I found a workaround using websocket. Here the url https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

It *is* possible to receive notifications in the browser (as long as the browser is Chrome). A tutorial for that is [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client).

jQuery is a Javascript library that has nothing to do with GCM.